# Browser incompatible issue with scrollbar

Tags: html, css

Can anybody help me with making this link compatible. there is a small gap under the scrollbar in Chrome, and IE.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DUySq/)

I try to play with:

```
height:--px
```

within the scrlDiv but it change the whole table

Comment: Why are you using 2 div while you can have a scroll with one div only?

Comment: thanks, good point, let me see

Comment: I removed it,but it still having this issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix what you have you can use `overflow-y: scroll` for the second `div`:

```
<div id="scrlDiv" style="padding:0px;height:112px;width:21px;overflow-y:scroll">
```

But I suggest to use **only one** div with scroll:

```
<div ID=DetDiv class="wrap" style="background-color:yellow;height:112px;width:200px;overflow-x:hidden" >
```

Comment: Thanks you figured it out.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are doing the scrolling separate from the main div - you will have to coordinate them manually.

Anyway, it seems that the problem is the "overflow: scroll" on the "wrap" div. It should be:

```
overflow-y: scroll
```

I'm also not sure why you have inline styles on elements that have classes and IDs - easy to define them in a separate CSS.

Comment: Thank you, I usually do it inline, and when i deploy i put it in separate file. thanks